# How to upgrade Azure Cloud Service when endpoints configuration is changed?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I've added **a new endpoint** in Azure Cloud Service configuration. Now I would like to upgrade the deployment **without downtime**.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a hosted service, you would publish the new version to the Staging Deployment. When both services run you swap the VIPs. This will make the Staging Deployment (with the additional endpoint) become accessible to your users instantly - there should be no downtime for your users.

Afterwards you delete the Staging Deployment (which now is your former deyploment without the new endpoint).